# Am I misunderstanding C# classes?

Tags: c#, class

I have a class that is designed to pull together various bits of data, and run some logic tests, and finally builds some output.

My application is student and hospital based (students create patient reports). Every time a student finishes a patient report, a class is called, which performs the above (basically builds the "credits" they've earned).

My understanding of instantiating a class and running a method, is that all the internals of the class, any data accrued and logic etc... is isolated to that class only?

ie. if a few students finish reports at the same time, and for each one, the class is instantiated and the method to rebuild their credits is called... one class's data would/should not 'leak' into another. Right??

Sorry if this is a bit vague, but for brevity, I've excluded any logic code that is working.

My issue is that the output is becoming 'mixed'.. ie. students have results from patient reports that aren't theirs.

```
public class Attainment
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int PatientID { get; set; }

    static DataTable dtAttainmentList;
    static DataTable dtClassroomData;


    public Attainment()
    {
        dtAttainmentList = new DataTable();
        dtAttainmentList.Columns.Add("boxUID", typeof(string));
        dtAttainmentList.Columns.Add("type", typeof(int));
        dtAttainmentList.Columns.Add("patientID", typeof(int));
    }

    public static void Rebuild(int thisStudentID, int thisPatientID)
    {
        Attainment test = new Attainment();
        test.StudentID = thisStudentID;
        test.PatientID = thisPatientID;
        test.GenerateAttainments(); 
    }

    public void GenerateAttainments()
    {
        // I've ommitted other methods here for brevity, but basically:
    
        dtClassroomData = GetClassroomData();
    
        // delete old records from database
        
        // run new logic

        // insert new records into database
    }

    
    DataTable GetClassroomData()
    {
        // creates new datatable
        // populates from the database 
        // returns the datatable
    }

}
```

Comment: You made the DataTables field variables static that means they are shared between instances of the class. Why are they static?

Comment: "I've excluded..." - just about anything that would let us *see what you're seeing*.

Comment: Well, it seems my misunderstanding of the "static" modifier is the cause... I wanted the DataTables to be unique to that class.

Comment: To be clear, if I wanted the DataTables to be unique and only accessible to each instance, would they have to be Private??